# Optimizing SPARQL queries on Fuseki using ttl

Tags: ajax, sparql, fuseki

I have been working on generating a ttl file via Apache Jena. This file is being queried using Apache Fuseki but I am noticing that the more data I add, the slower the query is becoming. I am using an ajax call from javascript to display the results on a webpage. Is there a better configuration or a way that I can optimize the queries? I know for a fact that the ttl file is going to grow as more data is predicted to be added.

For example this is one of the queries I am using:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 

PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/> 
PREFIX ore: <http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/> 
SELECT ?Register ?Id ?Date ?Type ?Lang ?TypeOfCover ?Spine ?Note (count(?Deed) as ?TotalDeeds)  
WHERE{ 
  ?Register dcterms:creator ?Author. 
  ?Register dcterms:identifier ?Id. 
  ?Register dcterms:type ?Type. 
  optional{?Register locah:dateCreatedAccumulatedString ?Date.} 
  optional{?Register <http://natarchives.com.mt/notarypedia/ontology#coverType> ?TypeOfCover.} 
  optional{?Register <http://natarchives.com.mt/notarypedia/ontology#spineWidth> ?Spine.} 
  optional{?Register <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#note> ?Note.}  
  optional{?Register ore:aggregates ?Deed.} 
  optional{?Register dcterms:language ?Lang.} 
  ?Author foaf:firstName "Giacomo". 
  ?Author foaf:familyName "Zabbara"} 
group by ?Register ?Id ?Date ?Type ?Lang ?TypeOfCover ?Spine ?Note
```

where it takes about 10s to display the results, which is quite annoying for someone who wants to display the results there and then on a UI

Comment: This is really vague. Please consider adding example config/code to narrow down as much possible towards the problem you are currently facing for others to assist you.

Comment: *"This file is being queried using Apache Fuseki but I am noticing that the more data I add, the slower the query is becoming"* - which is (in most cases) natural given that more data has to be scanned, joined, processed, right?

Comment: Agreed but isn't there a way to make the query scalable?

Comment: The query itself is pretty simple, a bunch of left-joins because of optional data. Although I think it should be faster, depends on the query execution plan. Can you say something about your setup? Is it TDB or just in-memory? How big is your dataset? How many triples? How much memory do you assigned to Fuseki?

Comment: My setup is a ttl file that has been uploaded on a Fuseki server (Therefore in-memory). There are 245901 triples and I have no idea how to check how much memory has been assigned to Fuseki. I am also thinking whether the issue might be in the ajax call...if this is where the delay is taking place

Comment: you can try without ajax first by using the Apache Jena CLI tools: http://ftp.fau.de/apache/jena/binaries/apache-jena-3.13.1.tar.gz - extract it, and then use `bin/sparql --data path_to_data_file --query ["query_string"|path_to_queryfile}`

Comment: I do think it is the ajax query...when looking at the logs of fuseki I am currently having a 25ms execution time. When I get the execution time of Ajax I am getting a 2.387s...how can I solve the time difference?